# python color reduction quantization

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, quantization

I am looking for a way to reduce colors in a clever way which preserves rare hues.

For example if you take the astronaut image and add a small square of a bright and different hue (green in this case). The color gets lost if you reduce the colors to a certain amount. It's there in 256 colors, but is lost in 32 colors (see treemap).

[image]

[image]

[image]

And there are way too many quite similar colors and hues of orange and gray in the reduction. (even in the 32 color, which I don’t need).

So I wonder if there is a kind of hue preserving color reduction with a weighting in hue difference. I have tried many libraries but none is good at this. This is Imagemagick.

Or do I have to implement it myself?

Maybe like so:

- Reduce to 256 colors (this is ok for nearly all images, smaller data)
- Loop through colors and compare and sort out pretty similar colors with CIEDE2000 DeltaE
- get remaining unique colors from PIL
- convert to HSV color model
- make a histogram to with specific bins (Hue 0 – 10 for red, 11 – 30 for orange…)
- loop again through colors and increase the accepted color distance DeltaE to some amount
- but keep the color if the compared colors go over the histogram bin borders

I don't know how to check for the histogram borders.

Comment: Typically this is done using k-means I think. Have you tried this?

Comment: yes, of course this reduction is k-means

Comment: question requires [mre], so we have something to debug. can't even speculate until you provide that.

Comment: Your small square is red not green!

Comment: Thanks Mark. I did not see that small square. I thought it was the large red square.  My apologies to the OP.

Comment: https://austinpoor.com/blog/algorithmic-color-palettes  A nice post that faces this problem. I tried wu-quant, octree and other clustering methods. Non is hue sensitive enough. Looks like I will have to try implement it. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In Imagemagick you could try -mean-shift.  It takes into account both location and color.  See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=4&sid=77516589270dc747fbc7cba3197a79c4

Here are two results.

```
convert astronaut.jpg -mean-shift 21x21+10% y.png
```

[image]

```
convert astronaut.jpg -mean-shift 51x51+10% z.png
```

[image]

If this is what you want, OpenCV also has a meanShift. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga432a563c94eaf179533ff1e83dbb65ea

Comment: The imagemagick link does not seem to work. I found two related links: https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=25504, https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#mean-shift

Comment: oh, this looks promising. Do you know how many different colors remain after mean Shift ? looks like many on my software but took only a screenshot. Reducing them to 32 with k-means again kills the green box

Comment: tried it with the wand mean_shift(51, 51, color_distance=0.1). leaves way too many unique colors left. increasing parameters to 71 71 gets really slow and not much better.

Comment: the opencv meanshift seems to be called pyrMeanShiftFiltering() now but looks like the same.  It does reduce the colors but you get quite similar groups like long bands of close colors.

Comment: No, I do not. It is not guaranteed to have  a limited number. I suppose the number depends upon the convergences and number of iterations.  Sorry I was in a hurry for an appointment and did not have time to check the number of unique colors.  Mean-shift is more of a smoothing and noise reduction while reducing colors.

Comment: yes, you are right. Mean-shift more smoothes than reduces colors. It creates quite a few similar colors. which I have then tried to remove with k-means. But k-means looks for high volume colors and leaves small but different colors aside. But nice idea.